# How to work with dto from two independent modules

Tags: java

I have two independent sub modules which parse some data. One use internet second using web services. Result is some DTO with same variable. Now I need to format this dtos in my main modules but how I can do this without duplicity ? I can not use some common module which will contain interface used by my sub modules

```
public static String formatData(submoduleA.DataDto data) {
//this will be duplicity
    return ...
}

public static String formatData(submoduleB.DataDto data) {
//this will be duplicity
    return ...
}
```

Comment: You should duplicate DTO's for each module for best practice

Comment: yea man that how it is now. But I dont know how I can format this 2 DTO's without duplicity

Comment: If you want to indicate a plural from, the right way is: DTOs. An apostrophe between the word and the s indicates genitive singular, e.g. the DTO's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract base DTO for common functionality. You can store that DTO in a common module and reference to that from ModuleA and ModuleB

```
public abstract class BaseDto{
    public String formatData()
}

public class DataDto extends BaseDto{
    public String formatData(){
        return ...  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an interface, let's say `CommonDataDto`, and code against this interface.

```java
public static String formatData(CommonDataDto data) {
    String formatted = data.getType() + data.getId();
    // ...
    return formatted;
}
```

Then you can either hava both `submoduleA.DataDto` and `submoduleB.DataDto` implement it, or, if you cannot change these classes, create an adapter for both.